# Java Implementing Functions On A Tree

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, element

I am working on a problem that asks me to implement several functions for the given interfaces.

I have an interface that is a single node in a tree, and an interface that is the tree.

*TreeNode*:

```
package main;

import java.util.List;

public interface TreeNode<E> {
    public E getElement();
    public void setElement(E elem);
    public void setChild(TreeNode<E> child);
    public TreeNode<E> getFirstChild();
    public List<TreeNode<E>> getChildren();
    public void setNextSibling(TreeNode<E> sibling);
    public TreeNode<E> getNextSibling();
    public int size();
    public int height();
    public List<TreeNode<E>> getPreOrder();
    public List<TreeNode<E>> getPostOrder();
    public String toString(TreeNode<E> node);
}
```

*Tree*:

```
package main;

import java.util.List;

public interface Tree<E> {
    public TreeNode<E> getRoot();
    public int size();
    public int height();
    public List<TreeNode<E>> getPreOrder();
    public List<TreeNode<E>> getPostOrder();
    public void makeEmpty();
    public boolean isEmpty();
    public int height(TreeNode<E> node);
    public int depth(TreeNode<E> node);
}
```

I am asked to:

> Implement these interfaces using the last-child/previous-sibling
>   method. Create MyTreeNode.java and MyTree.java that will extend Tree and TreeNode.

*MyTreeNode.java* is defined as:

> An implementation that extends TreeNode.java.

*MyTree.java* is defined as:

> An implementation that extends Tree.java.

So I have begun to construct *MyTree.java*. The problem is, I do not know how to "**extend**" the interface and implement the methods. To me, it sounds like it want's me to **implement** the interfaces and construct the methods that were defined. As far as I know only an interface can extend another interface.

Another question is, how will I create many of these functions without proper left and right nodes? I believe that I am not allowed to modify the existing interfaces (*Tree.java*, and *TreeNode.java*).

Can anybody please help in explaining to me in layman's terms what I am supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 0):

Your class needs to [implement the interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/usinginterface.html), like:

```
public class MyTree<E> implements Tree<E> {
   // implement the methods of interface.
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I thought. Could you recommend how to create a variable to hold the root node and left and right children? I am unsure of this because the interface does not include these.

Answer (score 0):

1. In java, you can only *extend* a class, and *implement* an interface. you're correct that only interface can extend another interface. I think the problem wants to create a class that *implement* the interface.
2. In your implementation, you'll define the proper left & right nodes. Therefore, in each of the specific function that you're implementing, you can implement refer to these fields directly.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question on terminologies:

Yes, you are right, your instructor/TA is simply not writing it accurately (May be they are more from a C++ background which there is not strict differentiation between interface/base-class and extends/implements).  I believe your interpretation is actually what they are looking for.

As the question explicitly mention about implementing using "last-child, prev sibling" (in contrast to the "first-child, next-sibling" in interface), I believe you should not implement using left/right (which actually means storing both prev and next sibling, for which seems defeating the purpose of the exercise).  I think they are simply making the question tricky and not realistic but it is fun to find the way.

One way to do without storing "next sibling" is store and extra attribute in node, which is parent.  "First-child,Next-Sibling" and "Last-Child,Prev-Sibling" is actually the same thing, which means to represent

```
   A
   |
   V
[B C D]
```

First child, Next Sibling is storing:

```
   A
   |
   V
   B -> C ->D
```

Last Child, Previous Sibling, if my guess is right, is storing

```
   A
   +--------+
            V
   B <- C <-D       (and B,C,D is storing a parent ref pointing to A)
```

So, in order to implement `TreeNode.firstChild()`, you simply need to go to its `lastChild()`, and keep iterating thru `prevSibling` until you find a node without `prevSibling` (i.e. node without previous sibling means it is the first one in children).

Similarly, to implement `TreeNode.nextSibling()`, you need to go to its `parent`'s `lastChild`, and keep finding a node with `prevSibling` equals to `this` (i.e. find the node having myself as previous sibling, which means the node is my next sibling).

---

Some pseudo-code:

```
/** Tree node implementation using "last-child-prev-sibling" */
MyTreeNode<E> implements TreeNode<E> {
    MyTreeNode<E> parent;
    MyTreeNode<E> lastChild;
    MyTreeNode<E> prevSibling;

    // I bet it is add child, which add a new child to the last
    public void setChild(TreeNode<E> child) {
        if (! (child instanceof MyTreeNode)) {
            throw new SomeKindOfImpatibleTypeException();
        }
        MyTreeNode<E> newLastChild = (MyTreeNode<E>) child;
        newLastChild.parent = this;
        newLastChild.previousChild = this.lastChild;
        this.lastChild = newLastChild;
    }

    public TreeNode<E> getNextSibling() {
        if (this.parent == null) {
            return null;
        }
        MyTreeNode<E> n = this.parent.lastChild;
        if (n == this) {
            return null;
        }
        for ( ; n != null; n = n.prevSibling) {
            if (n.prevSibling == this) {
                return n;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public TreeNode<E> firstChild() {
        if (lastChild == null) {
             return null;
        }
        for (TreeNode<E> n = lastNode; 
             n.prevSibling != null; 
             n=n.prevSibling) {
        }
        return n;
    }
}
```

Just to give you the idea on how to implement 2 key methods and the other is left to yourself

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing up this question. My professor can be vague like that sometimes. How I would implement these functions exactly? I'm at a loss with where to go next since there is no predefined root or left/right children.

Comment: I have already give you the logic for 2 key methods.  It will be super easy if you have left-right/prev-next child but I doubt if it is what your professor is looking for.  Lemme update with some code

Comment: I have updated my code to suit your pseudocode. Here is a pastebin of my current code: http://pastebin.com/q9yLJXxM The thing I'm working on now is preorder and postorder traversal. However, I am not sure how to accomplish this without left and right children. I am sorry I am not understanding totally, I am new to this. Thanks.

Comment: Not able to see your pastebin code at work.  But postorder/preorder traversal should be straight-forward, if you have `getFirstChild()` and `getNextSibling()` implemented.  Your traversal code can simply make use of these methods. e.g. preOrderTraverse(){ resultList += this; for (n = firstChild(); n != null; n = n.getNextSibling()) { resultList+= n.preOrderTraverse(); }`

Comment: I don't have `getFirstChild()` implemented yet. My two data members I have now are `lastChild` and `prevSibling`, both of which I can't see how they would help with `getFirstChild()`. I am probably mistaken though. I need some way to access the next element down, and not an element on the same line (sibling) but I don't have data members for these. Would I just create one for this purpose?

Comment: `getFirstChild()` should be super easy, just check my previous description: just go to lastChild, keep finding its previous until you find one with no prev sibling.  That one is the "first child"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90841/discussion-between-nic-and-adrian-shum).

Comment: I have added my `getFirstChild()` and `getPreOrder()` to the chat if you have a chance to look at them. Thanks.